# Send a success response to POST request

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, routes

I've got the following ajax call:

```
function sendRequest(quote, author){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: window.location.pathname,
        data: {quote: quote, author: author},
        dataType: JSON,
        success: function(){console.log("Data sent!");},
        error: function(error){console.log("ran into an error")}
    });
}
```

And here is my server (using express) handling the post request,

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){res.status(200).end("Success!")});
```

However, the console doesn't print "`Data Sent`". Instead, it prints "`ran into an error`"

Everything else is tested and is working correctly

Comment: try consoling the error like this : console.log("ran into an error :: ", error);
the error may help you find the issue.

Comment: `dataType: JSON,` - should that be `dataType: "JSON",`

Comment: Did you forget to `return false;` at the bottom of your submit function (if you're using a submit button)?

Comment: @PHPglue, nope, I did that

Answer (score 1):

First of all dataType should be `'json'` not `JSON`

Then check the console log for specific error.